# How to pass starting values in matrix form?

Tags: fitting, distributions

Consider the following MWE, where I try to pass starting values to FindDistributionParameters[]:

```
ρ=0.1; 
n=2; 
data=RandomVariate[MultivariateTDistribution[{0,0},{{1,ρ},{ρ,1}},10],100];
emptyμ[n_] := Table[Subscript[μf, i], {i, 1, n}];
emptyΣ[n_] := 
  Table[Subscript[σf^(1 + KroneckerDelta[i, j]), 
    Sort[{i, j}]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
fit = FindDistributionParameters[data, 
   MultivariateTDistribution[emptyμ[n], 
    emptyΣ[n], ν]];
```

I tried to add starting values to FindDistributionParameters[] as:

```
p = Flatten[{emptyμ[n], emptyΣ[n], ν}]
p0 = Flatten[{Mean[data], Covariance[data], 5}]
start1 = {p, p0}\[Transpose]
start2 = Rule @@@ %
start3 = {emptyμ[n] -> Mean[data], emptyΣ[n] -> Covariance[data] , ν -> 5}

fit = FindDistributionParameters[data, 
   MultivariateTDistribution[emptyμ[n], 
    emptyΣ[n], ν], start1(*start2, start3*)];
```

However, nothing works.

Also, is it possible to pass only starting values for one of the required parameters, e.g. `start4 = {{ν, 5}}`?

Comment: Hm weird. I strongly believe that this is a bug. I would appreciate it if you contacted Wolfram Support about it.

Comment: Have you got an evaluation order problem?  Would wrapping `Evaluate` round `MultivariateTDistribution[...]` help?

Comment: Thank you @HenrikSchumacher, I just opened a Question in Wolfram's community forum - unfortunately I do not have access to their advanced technical support.

Comment: @mikado, just tried - no joy.

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean?  Is there a specific error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**  I've removed my answer about blaming the problem on using `Subscript` (although I think that one should avoid subscripts almost always).

I'm now pretty sure the issue is that the covariance term is listed twice in the starting values:

```
start1 = {p, p0}\[Transpose]
```

[image: Duplicate starting values]

This is fixed with

```
start1 = DeleteDuplicates[{p, p0}\[Transpose]]
```

But sometimes the maximum number of iterations might need increasing.  Also, it might be best to create a table of log likelihood values keeping `ν` as an integer and choose the integer value that maximizes the log of the likelihood.